# R: Grouping by columns, regardless of order, then conducting function on tertiary column

Tags: r, grouping

I have the output from multiple `TSdist` functions to test the difference between multiple time series. The resultant matrix has been converted into a data frame using I have used `melt` to convert into a single data frame. With the first column representing the row ID as a column, the second representing the colnames. Im attempting to calculate the average similarity between the whole period.

Im attempting to group by the first two columns, performing and operation on the third. Here is an example data frame.

```
df <- data.frame(A = factor(x = c("A", "B", "A", "A"), levels = c("A", "B")),
             B = factor(x = c("B", "A", "A", "A"), levels = c("A", "B")),
             C= c(2,3,6,5))
```

Ive attempted to use `dplyr` to group by the first two columns. However, the location of the column needs to be ignored when performing the operation. For example the first row in the above data frame should be grouped with the second row as they are both A and B. With rows 3 and 4 naturally being grouped, performing a function on each group using the third column, eg. `mean()`.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two ways to approach this using `dplyr`.  If the number of levels is low, you can just create a new variable of the interaction, and use `fct_recode` to fix things (e.g. `BA` to `AB`).

This solution looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
df %>%
  mutate(
    AB = interaction(A, B, sep = ""),
    AB = fct_recode(AB, AB = "BA")
  )
```

A more robust solution takes a few more steps, but should work regardless of the number of levels in your actual data set:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  mutate(id = 1:length(A)) %>%
  gather(group_id, group, A:B) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(
    AB = paste0(sort(group), collapse = ""),
    C = C[1]
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch.  I usually just use `library(tidyverse)`, so I am terrible about remember which function is from which package.  fixed!

Answer (score 4):

You could do ... (same idea as @MelissaKey's `gather` approach) ...

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

# add a grouping variable found by sorting and pasting the first two cols
df[, g := 
  vapply(transpose(.SD), function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse=" "), "", USE.NAMES = FALSE)
, .SDcols=1:2]

# aggregate the third column with it
df[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=g, .SDcols=3]

#      g   C
# 1: A B 2.5
# 2: A A 5.5
```

You can pass column names in `.SDcols` instead of positions, and it is generally better practice. See the first FAQ in `vignette("datatable-faq")` for background if interested.

Comment: Also a viable approach that works, just not a fan of `data.table` notation!